# Трудно ли переписать драйвер для работы на win 7,8,10?

Tags: windows, драйвер

Есть драйвер для беспроводного usb, работающий на xp. Трудно ли его переписать под "старшие" версии windows? С учетом, что конкретно драйверами никогда не занимался и исходников тоже нет. Только .sys и .inf файлы драйвера

Comment: Если железе не программировал то сложно будет тебе, и еще зависит под что надо (железо).

Comment: Если исходника нет, то слово "переписать" как-то не к месту. Пишите заново.